# Checkout page not working on SOME computers

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9.3.10

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.10 and I have a checkout page where all fields of the checkout page are displayed on the page at the same time. It was working fine until about 2 weeks ago. Now after I enter my shipping information suddenly some fields I cannot click on. The mouse just stays as an arrow and I am unable to select shipping method, enter credit card info or even go back and change my name. Some fields remain clickable but not all. And here's the kicker: my developers CANNOT reproduce the problem! They say everything is fine when they try it (they aren't local). Why would this problem occur for some and not others? (yes we had customers call with the same issue)

Yes, I tried different browsers which are all up to date and it still happens. Java is up to date, my computer OS is up to date (it happens on MAC and PC, but I am using a PC).

Can ANYONE offer me ANY possibility why this might be happening??

Comment: If you can reproduce it in some of your systems and you have developers at hand I think a remote access / screen sharing tool should help them to see it "in action"?

Comment: When you are able to reproduce it, do you see anything in the console.log?

Comment: No nothing in the console.log

Answer (score 0):

There are cross browser testing services that might help you in this case.

These services provide, many native browsers for testing purposes in almost all environments and versions which can be accessed by you as well as the developers.

If you are able to reproduce the issue on these browser, you devs will be able to reproduce too.

They also provide initial free trial which will be enough for you in this test case.You can check following;

https://www.browserstack.com/

https://crossbrowsertesting.com/